# Applying Schema to part of a text file

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, schema

I have text file with the following format:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0
a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | f1 | g1 | i1 
a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | f2 | g2 | i2  
a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | f3 | g3 | i3 
a4 | b4 | c4 | d4 | f4 | g4 | i4  
a5 | b5 | c5 | d5 | f5 | g5 | i5
```

I read this file in Scala as:

```
val df = ss.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("delimiter","|"))
      .option("header", "false")
      .load("hdfsDir/myfile.txt")
```

Now I want to apply three different schemes to first record, second record and to the rest of my text file, meaning:

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 <<== first schema 
 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0  <<== second schema
```

and the third schema should be applied to the rest of the file

```
 a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | f1 | g1 | i1 
 a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | f2 | g2 | i2 
 a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | f3 | g3 | i3  
 a4 | b4 | c4 | d4 | f4 | g4 | i4  
 a5 | b5 | c5 | d5 | f5 | g5 | i5
```

For that I created three different schemes as:

```
val firstSchema=StructType(Array(
                StructField("ones",StringType,nullable=true),
                StructField("twos",StringType,nullable=true),
                StructField("threes",StringType,nullable=true),
                StructField("fours",StringType,nullable=true)
                ));

val secondSchema=StructType(Array(                                        
                    StructField("sixes",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("sevens",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("eights",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("nines",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("tens",StringType,nullable=true)
                    StructField("zeros",StringType,nullable=true)
                    ));

val restSchema=StructType(Array(
                    StructField("firstfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("secondfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("thirdfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("fourthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("fifthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("sixthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("seventhfield",StringType,nullable=true)
                    ));
```

Now I want to apply the previous three schemes to the three parts of the text file( first record, second record, rest of records)

I tried the following code to apply first schema to first record:

```
val firstdf = spark.createDataFrame(
  df.head,
  firstSchema
)

val seconddf = spark.createDataFrame(
      df.take(2).drop(1),
      secondSchema
    )

val restdf = spark.createDataFrame(
      df,
      restSchema
    )
```

But it does not works?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. I think there should be 3 different dataframes.

Comment: Yes, there should be three different Dataframes, but I mentioned just one assuming that the solution will be applied to the three dataframes in same way. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found to fix this issue is by applying one general schema to whole text file, and then take take the first and second rows out of the schema:

```
val restSchema=StructType(Array(
                    StructField("firstfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("secondfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("thirdfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("fourthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("fifthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("sixthfield",StringType,nullable=true),
                    StructField("seventhfield",StringType,nullable=true)
                    ));
val df = ss.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("delimiter","|"))
      .option("header", "false")
      .schema(restSchema)
      .load("hdfsDir/myfile.txt")


 val firstdf= df.filter("firstfield= '1'").select
 val seconddf= df.filter("firstfield= '6'").select

df
.withColumn("rnk",row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"firstfield")))
.where($"rnk">2).drop($"rnk")
```

Hope this can help.